# Creating drawables for each size and density of screen?

Tags: android, user-interface

Should we create multiple drawable folders for each size and screen density for the perfect user experience? For example:

drawable-small-ldpi

drawable-large-ldpi

drawable-small-mdpi

drawable-large-mdpi

drawable-small-xhdpi

drawable-large-xhdpi

...and so on for other densities and sizes.

**But this approach seems very difficult. Is there any other easy way to support all screen densities and sizes?**

Comment: This is the only way other than doing it programatically. In the case of launcher and action bar icons, Android Studio has a wizard which will totally automate this process.  For other images, you'll have to add different resolutions yourself.

Comment: It depends on the approach on how you want to present it, You can use scaleTypes for Images, Vector Asset, Even padding or margins and yes create a drawable for each size and density of the screen. Also for Padding and Margins sizes can be adjusted by dimens.xml

Answer (score 4):

just use vector in android.

Allows developers to easily use  drawables on all devices running Android 2.1 and above.

check this [link](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88)

Answer (score 0):

You can use class below

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SetViewSizeByPixel {

private LayoutParams params = null;
private DisplayMetrics metrics = null;
private Context mContext;
public static final int match_parent = -1;

public SetViewSizeByPixel(Context context) {
    metrics = getMetrics(context);
    this.mContext = context;
}

/**
 * 
 */

public int RH(int x) {
    return metrics.heightPixels * x / 1920;
}

public int RW(int x) {
    return metrics.widthPixels * x / 1080;
}

public int RH720p(int x) {
    return metrics.heightPixels * x / 1280;
}

public int RW720p(int x) {
    return metrics.widthPixels * x / 720;
}

public int RH(float x) {
    return (int) (metrics.heightPixels * x / 1920);
}

public int RW(float x) {
    return (int) (metrics.widthPixels * x / 1080);
}

/**
 * Metrics
 */

public DisplayMetrics getMetrics(Activity activity) {
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    return metrics;
}

public DisplayMetrics getMetrics(Context context) {
    return getMetrics((Activity) context);
}

public DisplayMetrics getMetrics() {
    return metrics;
}

public int heightPixels() {
    return metrics.heightPixels;
}

public int widthPixels() {
    return metrics.widthPixels;
}

public float density() {
    return metrics.density;
}

public int densityDpi() {
    return metrics.densityDpi;
}

/**
 * Size
 */

public boolean height(View view, int height) {
    return size(view, -1, height);
}

public boolean width(View view, int width) {
    return size(view, width, -1);
}

public boolean square(View view, int x) {
    return size(view, x, x);
}

public boolean size(View view, int width, int height) {
    try {
        params = view.getLayoutParams();
        if (width != -1)
            params.width = width;
        else
            params.width = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;

        if (height != -1)
            params.height = height;
        else
            params.height = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SetSizeByPercent", e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Size with RW, RH.
 */

public boolean heightR(View view, int height) {
    return size(view, -1, this.RH(height));
}

public boolean widthR(View view, int width) {
    return size(view, this.RW(width), -1);
}

public boolean squareR(View view, int x) {
    return size(view, this.RW(x), this.RH(x));
}

public boolean sizeR(View view, int width, int height) {
    return size(view, RW(width), RH(height));
}

/**
 * Margin R
 */
public void marginTopR(View v, int top) {
    marginTop(v, RH(top));
}

public void marginR(View v, int lef, int top, int rig, int bot) {
    margin(v, RH(lef), RH(top), RH(rig), RH(bot));
}

public void marginR(View v, int x) {
    margin(v, RW(x), RH(x), RW(x), RH(x));
}

/**
 * Margin
 */
public void marginLeft(View v, int lef) {
    margin(v, lef, -1, -1, -1);
}

public void marginTop(View v, int top) {
    margin(v, -1, top, -1, -1);
}

public void marginRight(View v, int rig) {
    margin(v, -1, -1, rig, -1);
}

public void marginBottom(View v, int bot) {
    margin(v, -1, -1, -1, bot);
}

public void marginLeft(View v, int lef, boolean keepOldMargin) {
    int k = keepOldMargin ? -1 : 0;
    margin(v, lef, k, k, k);
}

public void marginTop(View v, int top, boolean keepOldMargin) {
    int k = keepOldMargin ? -1 : 0;
    margin(v, k, top, k, k);
}

public void marginRight(View v, int rig, boolean keepOldMargin) {
    int k = keepOldMargin ? -1 : 0;
    margin(v, k, k, rig, k);
}

public void marginBottom(View v, int bot, boolean keepOldMargin) {
    int k = keepOldMargin ? -1 : 0;
    margin(v, k, k, k, bot);
}

public void margin(View v, int margin) {
    margin(v, margin, margin, margin, margin);
}

public void margin(View v, int lef, int top, int rig, int bot) {
    if (v.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v
                .getLayoutParams();
        lef = (lef == -1) ? p.leftMargin : lef;
        top = (top == -1) ? p.topMargin : top;
        rig = (rig == -1) ? p.rightMargin : rig;
        bot = (bot == -1) ? p.leftMargin : bot;

        p.setMargins(lef, top, rig, bot);
        v.requestLayout();
    }
}

public LayoutParams getParams() {
    return params;
}

public void setParams(LayoutParams params) {
    this.params = params;
}

/**
 * Text Size
 */
public void textSize(TextView tv, int size) {
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size);
}

public void textSize(View view, int size) {
    try {
        ((TextView) view).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", e.toString());
    }
}

public void textSizeR(TextView view, int size) {
    view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, RH(size));
}

public void textSizeR(View view, int size) {
    try {
        ((TextView) view).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, RH(size));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", e.toString());
    }
}

/**
 * Animation & TypeFace
 */
public Animation getAnimation(int id) {
    return AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, id);
}

public Typeface getTypeface(String typefacePath) {
    return Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), typefacePath);
}

// public void setSize(View v,int w,int h){
// float hrate = MyActivity.Height/1920f;
// size(v, (int) (w*hrate),(int)(h*hrate));
// }
}
```

Usage in OnCreate()

```
    SetViewSizeByPixel setSize = new SetViewSizeByPixel(this);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = setSize.getMetrics(this);
    setSize.height(layout_banner, metrics.heightPixels * 100 / 1024);
    layout_banner.setPadding(metrics.widthPixels * 15 / 600, 0,
            metrics.widthPixels * 15 / 600, 0);
    setSize.marginBottom(layout_banner, metrics.heightPixels * 25 / 1024);
    // textview
    setSize.width(txt_title, metrics.widthPixels * 500 / 600);
```

600x1024 : It is the sample screen density

15, 100, 500 : It is a unit in pixels

Hope help you !!!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but could you please explain whats happening on doing so? I cannot seem to understand what this does. Thanks @Nyugen

Comment: Try code a example. And build it on multiple screen